# Back button missing after segue

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, segue

So, in this scenario...

- I have three storyboards (A, B, and C).
- C is a common storyboard that both A and B at some point segue to with a storyboard reference.
- Storyboard A and B are both UITableViews with a list of news articles.
- When you click on one of the UITableViewCells, it will segue to Storyboard C.
- In Storyboard C, I want to be able to go back to where I came from (A or B). So, I added a Navigation bar to Storyboard C and added a back button.
- In the UINavigationItem in Storyboard C, I set the `Back Button` value to Back.

When I build and run, the navigation bar is there in Storyboard C, but no back button in the navigation bar in Storyboard C. In Storyboard A and B, I even put those UITableViews inside a Navigation Controller thinking that to include a back bar, it needs to have come from a navigation controller first, and that didn't work.

When I go to the outlets page of the UINavigationItem, this is what it looks like:

[image]

How do I add the back button to Storyboard C?

FYI I'm not that experienced of an iOS developer, so there may be some obvious things that I'm not aware of.

**EDIT**: I use a `show segue` for both A-->C and B-->C segues.

Comment: How you are showing your storyboard c controller? is it present modally or push in the navigation?

Comment: @NiravD it's a show segue

Answer (score 3):

You should setup your views like this:

- View A (Table View) ... `Embed Navigation Controller` For `View A`
- View B (Table View) ... `Embed Navigation Controller` For `View B`
- View C (Normal View) .... **Do Not** Embed Navigation Controller For View C
- Create Segue from `view A` -> `View C`
- Create Segue from `view B` -> `View C`

  You can see that, after you create Segue to `View C`, In `View C` will appear the navigation bar automatically because you just need to embed navigation controller for the root view (in this case is `View A` and `View C`)

This is how you can Embed Navigation Controller to a View Controller

[image]

After you do like I said. You will get the story board like this:
[image]

That's how you need to setup your story board.

So now you have 2 branch of navigation

1. View A -> View C (Root is View A)
2. View B -> View C (Root is View B)

Hope it helps you

Comment: Yes, but in my scenario, that last view is a storyboard reference. Inside that storyboard that's being referenced, it doesn't wrap it in navigation controller.

Comment: https://www.newventuresoftware.com/blog/organizing-xcode-projects-using-multiple-storyboards 

If you do like this, you just need to dismiss the storyboard C when user click the back button for moving back.
You can drag the back button bar item into your navigation bar in story board C to make it always visible

Answer (score 0):

I think your navigation bar gets hidden when come back from another storyboard. In that case you have to show your navigation bar forcefully. In your first view controller in storyboard C. Try the following code:

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
 {
     [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:animated];
     [super viewWillAppear:animated];
 }
```

**swift3**

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: animated)
super.viewWillAppear(animated)
}
```

Comment: if user presnt the VC the nav bar is not available on that time

Comment: @RobAveryIV For your future conversion of Obj-C to Swift use [this](https://objectivec2swift.com/)

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik according to his question he is using segues with navigation bar. So

Answer (score 0):

- If you're pushing a ViewController "C" on navigation stack then you need to pop that controller on back button tap.

  **pushing**

  `self.navigationController?.pushViewController(ViewControllerC, animated: true)`

  **poping**

  `self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)`
- If you're presenting a ViewController "C" then you need to dismiss that controller on back button tap.

  **presenting**

  `self.presentViewController(ViewControllerC, animated:true, completion:nil)`

  **dismissing**

  `self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)`

**EDIT**

you need to add this code like

When going from A -> C, you need to add this in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method of tableview (on tap of cell), ignore if you are using segue

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(ViewControllerC, animated: true)
```

When coming back from C -> A, you need to implement bar button action method like this in "C"

in `viewDidLoad()` method of view controller "C", add bar button programatically

```
let backBtn = UIButton(type: .custom)
backBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "imagename"), for: .normal)
backBtn.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)
backBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewControllerC.back), for: .touchUpInside)
let item2 = UIBarButtonItem(customView: backBtn) 

func back(sender: UIButton){
  self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

The same way you can do for View controller B also.

Comment: I don't know where exactly I put these in my code. In Storyboard A and B, they aren't NavigationControllers.